# found extra whitespace while using fscanf

Tags: c

I have a file:

```
hello:12312
Bye:333
Hey:22
```

so I read it using fscanf

```
 FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else
        {

            while(fscanf(file, "%[^:]:%d", word, &integer) != EOF)
            {
                printf("word: %s, integer: %d\n", word, integer);
            }

            fclose( file );
        }
```

And this is what I got:

```
word: hello, integer: 12312
word:
Bye, integer: 333
word:
Hey, integer: 22
```

So apparently there is a extra whitespace except for the first word, why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> All conversion specifiers other than [, c, and n consume and discard all leading whitespace characters before attempting to parse the input.

and the `\n` will remain the input stream after `"%d"`.

To correct add a leading space to the format speicifer to skip whitespace:

```
while(fscanf(file, " %[^:]:%d", word, &integer) == 2)
{
}
```

Changed the `!= EOF` to `== 2` to prevent accepting lines of the format `"hello:"` or `"hello"`.

Answer (score 3):

`%[^:]` will accept line endings.  If you want to skip putting leading whitespace into `word` try:

```
 " %[^:]:%d"
```

Answer (score 1):

add space at the beginning of your string format `" %[^:]:%d"`. this will avoid the newline problems in the scanf

```
 while(fscanf(file, " %[^:]:%d", word, &integer) != EOF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use the *scanf() functions to read an integer, the following newline isn't consumed.